# Tree branch combinations

Tags: .net, algorithm

The source data is a treeview represeting a system fault tree and I am trying to generate the cutsets (All the AND gate events included with all permutations from the OR gates)

For example, starting with this

```
Root 
---AND_GATE
------A
------B
---OR_GATE
------C1
------C2
------AND_GATE
---------D1
---------D2
---OR_GATE
------E1
------E2
------E3
---AND_GATE
------F
------G
```

Can be simplified like this:
A, B, (C1 | C2 | (D1, D2)), (E1|E2|E3), F, G

and the intent is to generate this result:

```
A , B, C1, E1, F, G
A , B, C1, E2, F, G
A , B, C1, E3, F, G

A , B, C2, E1, F, G
A , B, C2, E2, F, G
A , B, C2, E3, F, G

A , B, D1, D2, E1, F, G
A , B, D1, D2, E2, F, G
A , B, D1, D2, E3, F, G
```

I cannot think of a method to do combinations on a pattern that will vary in structure (nested ANDs and ORs) and size (width and depth). The tree can vary from 10s of elements to a thousand or more

and from there I was able to generate:

```
A, B, (C1 | C2 | (D1, D2)), (E1|E2|E3), F, G
```

but I got stuck again.

Any ideas or suggestions please.

Thank you!

```
  Public Class Cut
        Public Property Node As TreeNode
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property GT As String
        Public Property Elements As List(Of Cut)

        Public Sub New(n As TreeNode)
            Node = n
            Name = Node.Name
            GT = GetNodeType(Node)
        End Sub

        Public Function Trace() As String
            If Elements Is Nothing OrElse Elements.Count = 0 Then
                Return Name
            Else
                Dim ans As String = ""
                Dim sep As String = IIf(GT = "or", "|", ",").ToString
                For Each el As Cut In Elements
                    DbHelper.MergeIn(ans, el.Trace, sep)
                Next
                ans = Name & "=(" & ans & ")"
                Return ans
            End If
        End Function
    End Class

    Private Sub ReadTree(parent As TreeNode, collector As List(Of Cut))

        Dim pt, nt As Cut
        pt = New Cut(parent)

        Dim subcollector As New List(Of Cut)
        For Each node As TreeNode In parent.Nodes
            nt = New Cut(node)
            If node.GetNodeCount(True) = 0 Then
                If nt.GT = "be" Then subcollector.Add(nt)
            Else
                Call ReadTree(node, subcollector)
            End If
        Next
        pt.Elements = subcollector
        collector.Add(pt)

    End Sub
```

Here is an example

```
A(AND)
---A1
---A2(AND)
------B1
------B2(OR)
---------C1
---------C2
---A3(OR)
------D1
------D2
```

Calling ReadTree against the Node "A" generates this:

```
A1,A2=(B1,B2=(C1|C2)),A3=(D1|D2)
```

simplified as:

```
A1,(B1,(C1|C2)),(D1|D2)
```

the intended output is:

```
A1  B1  C1  D1  
A1  B1  C1  D2  
A1  B1  C2  D1  
A1  B1  C2  D2
```

Comment: I am not sure I follow. For the original example, there are 3 permutations of the C block  (C1 | C2 | (X)) and 3 for the E block (E1|E2|E3). I need all the other elements to repeat for each combination of the C and E elements.

Comment: Are you looking to find ALL combinations (there may be a lot), all of the MINIMAL combinations (far fewer), or all of the combinations above some fixed probability?

Comment: Minimal combinations. I have a specific use-case to do a specific assessment with the all the combinations so was thinking I will eliminate from those based on the probability threshold afterwards.